# Pass validation within a custom control up to forms it's placed on

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've created a custom form control that has a single select control that looks up its values from a REST service. In some cases, I pre-fill the control with a value parsed from another string. I have a validation that checks the value is in the list.

This works but when I place the control on a form the failed validation isn't passed up to the form the control is placed on.

I've created a simplified [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiselect-custom-form-field-validation) that doesn't have the service. The Base select has a simple 'required' validator. When this field is blank the submit button is correctly disabled. The custom control has a custom validator that checks 'Four' isn't selected, this highlights the field but doesn't disable the submit button. (you may need to edit the value in the custom control to get it started)

How do I pass the failed validation out of the custom control to the containing form so that it too is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

A custom control such as this should be dumb, that is it doesn't cleverly go and get the list from the service itself and try to perform its own validation. Doing this separates the logic from the presentation which is good [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Once the validator is in its own class it can be placed on the containing form to provide validation there and no need to pass the error result out of the component.

For the original problem where the validator "checks the value is in the list" the logic to get its list from the service also needs to separated out and passed to the custom control from the containing form. This will make it easy to pass the list into the validator as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you use reactive Forms try to avoid validators on the template (required min max etc...) and add them with [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators). In this case try removing required from html and add it to the component ts.

In a formGroup you can have:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
   customSelect: 'initialValue',
});
```

In this case the field customSelect will have the value 'initialValue', this is what you are using,

But you can also pass an array where the first value is your value and the second the validator:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
   customSelect: ['initialValue', Validators.required]
});
```

You can also pass multiple validators:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    customSelect: ['initialValue', [Validators.required, OtherValidator]]
});
```

And also you can check async Validators that will be the third value so the formGroup has at the end the following:

```
[controlState, validators, asyncValidators];
```

At the end your component will have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, NgControl, ControlValueAccessor, Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

const { required } = Validators;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
formGroup: FormGroup;

constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
) {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      customSelect: [[], required],
      baseSelect: [[], required]
    });
    this.oddNumbers();
  }

  oddNumbers() {
    this.formGroup.get('customSelect').setValue(["One", "Three", "Five"]);
    this.formGroup.get('baseSelect').setValue(["One", "Three", "Five"]);
  }

  evenNumbers() {
    this.formGroup.get('customSelect').setValue(["Two", "Four"]);
    this.formGroup.get('baseSelect').setValue(["Two", "Four"]);
  }

  clear() {
    this.formGroup.get('customSelect').setValue(null);
    this.formGroup.get('baseSelect').setValue(null);
  }
```

}
`

Also you can use a method called createForm() on ngOnInit() instead of adding your form on your constructor.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.oddNumbers();
}
createForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      customSelect: [[], required],
      baseSelect: [[], required]
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @perseus, I've moved the required validator as you suggest but it didn't affect the issue I raised in my question. The `notFourValidator` result inside the `multiselect.component` custom control is not being passed outside the control to invalidate the parent form in `app.component`.